# How to get remote user name from request

Tags: java, httprequest

I have used `request.getRemoteUser` but it gives `null` as output. Can someone tell me the proper steps how to get the remote user name?

Comment: what does this have to do with javascript or html? I'm removing those tags

Comment: @melihcelik probably should have removed it from the question itself, or is that even possible?

Answer (score 4):

From [API Doc](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.5/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29):

> Returns the login of the user making this request, if the user has been authenticated, or null if the user has not been authenticated. Whether the user name is sent with each subsequent request depends on the browser and type of authentication. Same as the value of the CGI variable REMOTE_USER.

It seems that your user is not authenticated. To make it authenticated you can for example use basic authentication. In this case client should send HTTP header Authorization:

`Authorization: Basic user:password`

Concatenation of `user:password` should be encoded using Base64 encoding.

Answer (score 2):

If `request.getRemoteUser` returns null, it means that the user is NOT authenticated (see [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29)). You need some kind of authentication method. `request.getRemoteUser` does not return the loginname the user used to log in to their computer. It returns the username used to log into the web application (although it is sometimes possible to use NTLM to automaticly log into a web application).